# Convert NGINX config to Apache

Tags: apache, vue.js, nginx, fastapi

Im running a VueJS + FastAPI app via NGINX, I have 2 routes, "/" and "/api"

/ serves a vuejs front end running on localhost:5300

/api serves fastapi backend running on localhost:5301

I can get it to work with following Nginx config, but need to port this config to Apache (httpd 2.4.6 on Centos 7)

I cant figure out the Apache directives and keep getting Invalid Host Header errors,

nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.netportal.corp.com netportal.corp.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.netportal.corp.com netportal.corp.com;
    error_page 404 =301 https://www.corp.com;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/star.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/star.key;
    
    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        rewrite ^/api/?(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5301;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5300/;
    }
}
```

this is my Apache config, and I keep getting Invalid Host Headers error

```
LoadModule  headers_module        /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule  proxy_wstunnel_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so


#### rcuat

ProxyRequests Off
RewriteEngine On

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/netportal_error.log

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName netportal.corp.com
    ServerAlias netportal
    Redirect / https://netportal.corp.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    
    ServerName netportal.corp.com
    ServerAlias netportal

    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/star.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/star.key

    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    RequestHeader set X-SCHEME https
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Location /api/>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:5301/    
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:5301/
    </Location>

    
    <Location />
        RequestHeader set X-SCHEME https
        ProxyPass        / http://0.0.0.0:5300/ nocanon
        ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:5300/
    </Location>
    # RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

</VirtualHost>
```

can someone help converting the / and /api directives to Apache syntax?

is there a converter tool to do this? I cant seem to find anything that works.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your configuration a bit.

Defined the correct modules for proxying to http backend.
Removed all the location directives which were no needed and would just complicate your life for what you really want to do.
Added missing trailing slashes (rule of thumb, if source ends up in trailing slash, destination should always end in trailing slash too).
Removed RewriteEngine since no rewrites are needed/used.

```
LoadModule  headers_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_headers.so
# for proxying to http you just need mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_http.so




#### rcuat

ProxyRequests Off

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/netportal_error.log

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName netportal.corp.com
    ServerAlias netportal
    #match trailing slashes in redirects and proxypass directives
    Redirect / https://netportal.corp.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName netportal.corp.com
    ServerAlias netportal

    SSLEngine On
    #no https backend, related directives removed

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/star.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/star.key

    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    RequestHeader set X-SCHEME https
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    # Proxypass should not go in location, it just makes a mess
    # Location is interpreted in the opposite order than proxypass too.

    # with proxypass most specific path must be defined first. More global last.
    # note that not matching source path and destiny path can cause issues with some backends depending how they behave, so examine backend behaviour carefully. because it definetly may be less troublesome to do proxypass /api/ http://backend/api/


    ProxyPass /api/ http://localhost:5301/
    ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://localhost:5301/

    ProxyPass        / http://0.0.0.0:5300/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:5300/
</VirtualHost>
```